# Using one script to disable 2 different scripts only if the specific enemy dies. Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-3.0

I have this script for my enemies health that I use for all my enemies. When the enemy dies I need it to disable the enemies movement. I have multiple different enemy movement scipts because some enemies move differently. How can I disable the movement of an enemy when that enemy dies? How can I do it like a GameObject?
[This in these pictures, for Enemy Movement, how can I make it so I can just drag and drop the script I want disabled into that box?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPUr2.png) [Second picture here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcXLW.png)

I have it technically working right now. I did a `public string EnemyMovement;` and just typed out the script name I needed disabled in the unity inspector tab. Then in my enemy health script, when the enemy dies, I run this command: `(this.GetComponent(EnemyMovement) as MonoBehaviour).enabled = false;`.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close already. I assume your EnemyMovement component is always another component on the same GameObject (the enemy).

If so, you can use a base class EnemyMovement and derive from that for the specific movement classes (BatMovement, SnakeMovement etc.). This way, you can call `this.GetComponent<EnemyMovement>()` in your health script to get the component direcly by the base type without using the public string.

It's best to avoid strings for this kind of problem, as the compiler can't check them for correctness and you can't easily replace e.g. a class name (and all it's references at once) in your IDE without also needing to change every related string afterwards.